# Put two menus in the same location

Tags: menus, multisite

Is it possible to put two different menus side by side in the same theme location?

I need this because i have a multisite instalation in wich i'll create a default menu that the subsite admins should not be able to edit.

On the other hand these sub site admins can make their own menu.

But this menu created by the sub site admins should be on the same place, at the same time as the default menu that i created.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just call the second menu below the first menu in the template file then style it with CSS?

Comment: Or maybe instead of them adding a new menu, they can just add new menu elements to your menu.

Comment: @DaveLak Well, didn't thought about doing this, will try it Thanks!

Comment: @Nikolay But than they would be able to delete the default menu itens

Comment: @VictorAkio Yes, you have to deny this somehow. But aren't they going to be able to delete the whole separate menu too then?

Comment: @Nikolay Yes, they will, but thats ok, they just cant alter the default menu that i've created.